# What is common AJAX convention for knowing a particular state when a page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax, parameters, session-state, state

This has been a question I've had since I started doing serious ajax stuff. Let me just give an example.

Let's say you pull a regular HTML page of a customer from the server. The url can look like this:

/myapp/customer/54

After the page is rendered, you want to provide ajax functionality that acts on this customer. In order to do this, you need to send the id "54" back to the server in each request.

Which is the best/most common way to do this? I find myself putting this in hidden form forms. I find it easy to select, but it also feels a bit fragile. What if the document changes and the script doesn't work? What if that id gets duplicated for css purposes 3 months from now, and thus breaks the page since there are 2 ids with the same name?

I could parse the url to get the value "54". Is that approach better? It would work for simple cases repeatedly. It might not work so well for complex cases where you might want to pass multiple ids, or lists of ids.

I'd just like to know a best practice - something robust that is clean, elegant and is given 2-thumbs up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to think like you don't have Ajax.

Let's say you have a form which is submitted using Ajax. How do you know what URL to send it to?

*The src attribute.* Simply have your script send the form itself. All the data is in the form already.

Let's say you have a link which loads some new data. How do you know the URL and parameters?

*The href attribute.* Simply have the script read the URL.

So basically you would always read the URL/data from the element being acted upon, similar to what the browser does.

Since your server-side code knows the ID's etc. when the page is being loaded, you can easily generate these URLs there. The client-side code will only need to read the attributes.

This approach has more than just one benefit:

- It makes it simpler where the URLs and data is stored, because they are put exactly in the attributes that you'd normally find then in HTML.
- It makes it easier to make your code work without JavaScript if you want to, because the URLs and all are already in places where the browser can understand them without JS.

**If you're doing something more complex than links/forms**

In a case where you need to allow more complex interactions, you can store the IDs or other relevant data in attributes. HTML5 provides the [data-* attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) for this purpose - I would suggest you use these even if you're not doing HTML5:

```
<div data-article-id="5">...</div>
```

If you have a more full-featured application on the page, you could also consider simply storing your ID in JS code. When you generate the markup in the PHP end, simply include a snippet in the markup  which assigns the ID to a variable or calls a function or whatever you decide is best.

Comment: +1 Exactly, let AJAX be the enhancement, not the backbone. With proper structure, everything you need is already there.

Comment: Let's say I have a 'div' tag that contains a title. When the user clicks this div tag, it becomes editable and the user can type and change it. When they unfocus or press enter, it becomes uneditable again and an ajax call is sent to the server to update the title of this entity. Where was this id stored to send the ajax request? Answer this question and you get a gold star ;)

Comment: Another example is dragging and dropping things and wanting those positions updated in the database as the user drops them. No form or anchors are used here either. Where does the ID come from in this case? I guess I understood it for forms... but I'm talking about all this extra stuff

Comment: Ahh, okay ;) I've been doing something similar, but I've been using 'id' on a 'div' tag instead, which I found conflicted with css and html rules overtime as things get modified. Your solution makes a lot of sense. I had no idea that you could just use a data attribute like this (I'm not too familiar with html5). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your form should work without javascript, so you probably have a hidden form input or something that contains the id value already. If not, you probably should.

It's all "fragile" in the sense that a small change will affect everything, not much you can do about that, but you don't always want to put it in the user's hands by reading the url or query string, which can be easily manipulated by the user. (this is fine for urls of course, but not for everything. Same rules that apply to trusting $_GET and query strings apply here).

Personally, I like to build all AJAX on top of existing, functional code and I've never had a problem "hooking" into what is already there.

---

> Not everything is a form though. For
>   example, let's say you click a "title"
>   and it becomes editable. You edit it,
>   press enter, and then it becomes
>   uneditable and part of the page again.
>   You needed to send an ID as part of
>   this. Also, what about moving things
>   around and you want those positions
>   updated? Here's another case where
>   using the form doesn't work because it
>   doesn't exist.

All of that is still possible, and not entirely difficult to do without javascript, so a form could work in either case, but I do indeed see what you're saying. In almost every case, there is some sort of unique id, whether it's a database id or file name, that can be used as the "id" attribute of the html that represents it. * Or the `data-` attribute as Jani Hartikainen has mentioned.

For instance, I have a template system that allows drag/drop of blocks of content. Every block has an id and every area that it can get dropped has one as well. I will use prefixes on the containing `div` id like "template-area_35" or "content-block_264". In this case, I don't bother to fallback w/o javascript, but it could be done (dropdown-> move this to area for example). In any case, it's a good use of the id attribute.

> What if that id gets duplicated for
>   css purposes 3 months from now, and
>   thus breaks the page since there are 2
>   ids with the same name?

If that happens (which it really shouldn't), someone is doing something wrong. It would be their fault if the code failed to work, and they would be responsible. Ids are by definition supposed to be **unique**.

Comment: Not everything is a form though. For example, let's say you click a "title" and it becomes editable. You edit it, press enter, and then it becomes uneditable and part of the page again. You needed to send an ID as part of this. Also, what about moving things around and you want those positions updated? Here's another case where using the form doesn't work because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Started writing a long comment stream, then just updated answer. Maybe if you could share a real case that you're currently dealing with it would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO putting is at a request parameter (i. e. ?customerId=54) would be good 'cos even if you can't handle AJAX (like in some old mobile browsers, command-line browsers and so) you can still have a reference to the link.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't too clear. I don't have a problem loading the page to start with. I also don't have a problem with sending the ajax calls. My question is... where is the best place to store the id when the page loads in the first place, if stored at all? Or is it better derived from the url and not stored in the document?

Comment: I don't see any problem with having it in a hidden input as long as you validate correctly on your backend, and not relying in the difficulty for a normal user to modify this hidden field. Given the fact that you have 1k reputation I don't think this is your case, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have an application that is aware of the entity "Customer", you should reflect this in your Javascript (or PHP, but since you're doing ajax I would put it in Javascript).

Instead of handmaking each ajax call you could wrap it into more domain aware functions:

Old scenario:

```
var customer_id = fetch_from_url();  // or whatever
ajax("dosomething", { "customer": customer_id }, function () {
    alert("did something!");
});
ajax("dosomethingelse", { "customer": customer_id }, function () {
    alert("did something else!");
});
```

New scenario:

```
var create_customer = function (customer_id) {

    return {
        "dosomething" : function () {
            ajax("dosomething", { "customer": customer_id }, function () {
                alert("did something!");
            });
        },
        "dosomethingelse": function () {
            ajax("dosomethingelse", { "customer": customer_id }, function () {
                alert("did something else!");
            });
        }
    };
}

var customer_id = fetch_from_url();  // or whatever
var customer = create_customer(customer_id);
// now you have a reference to the customer, you are no longer working with ids
// but with actual entities (or classes or objects or whathaveyou)
customer.dosomething();
customer.dosomethingelse();
```

To round it up. Yes, you need to send the customer id for each request but I would wrap it in Javascript in proper objects.

Comment: My question isn't how to do this, but in this line of code: "fetch_from_url();  // or whatever". I want to know what is the very best way to write this line of code. Apparently getting it from the url is not the best place because the user can simply change it as I am told by some people on here... so that leaves hidden form inputs, or hidden div's that contain the id value.